# IBM Filenet P8 subscription maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ibm-rad, filenet-p8

In my current project using Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3, IBM RAD 9.5 and Apache Maven 3.3.1

I'm going to use maven to build my artifacts, and specifically I'm asking which are the dependencies needed to correctly build a subscription's code module.

Moreover I would need to know their scope, since I'm not sure about which of them are already provided.

Thanks to this [Christopher Powell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544650/how-to-deploy-an-ibm-filenet-p8-subscription) I found this [Eclipse Plugin for ECM Developers](http://www.ecmdeveloper.com/getting-started/content-engine-4-5-1-and-beyond-installation/) but I'm not completely sure that the dependencies refer to the latest version of Content Platform Engine.

At the moment I found that `jace.jar` is the only clearly required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Code Module" run from an "Event Action", is run from inside FileNet; it is the youngest child within the Class Loader.

For basic coding, you only need Jace.jar to build your Code Module, and should not include Jace.jar within your Code Module (a Code Module can have more than one jar). 
For more advanced coding, please review this: [FileNet required Jars](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/gs_concepts.htm#gs_concepts__gs_required_jars)

When building, you should also use the Jace.jar from your Content Engine install. The Jace.jar on 5.2.1, will be different than the Jace.jar on 5.2.0.

If you start doing more advanced stuff, like calling SOAP from within the Code Module, then your dependency needs might cause problems with the Application Server (WAS or WebLogic etc), because you may end up with class loader issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the ACCE you can download a pack with all the required libs:
[image]

Then put all the libs in your artifact server and build your pom. And for the event action you should not need any additional libs for the ce libraries. So just your event actions jar should be enough. All the jars in the pom can go to a scope compile as all libs are already present on the CPE