# Custom subscription error in IBM Filenet p8

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

In my current project using Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3.
I deploy a content engine subscription to the system.
When I put a document in the system and my subscription runs, in the trace log I found this message:

```
2016-04-21T15:56:39.554 184668A9 CMOD FNRCE0000D - DEBUG CMCL searching in CodeModule for class org.apache.log4j.Logger
2016-04-21T15:56:39.554 184668A9 CMOD FNRCE0000D - DEBUG search for class org.apache.log4j.Logger in JAR/ZIP CodeModuleToCItem:0:0:application/java-archive:pdgov-filenet-subscription-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:state=U
2016-04-21T15:56:39.554 184668A9 CMOD FNRCE0000D - DEBUG path org/apache/log4j/Logger.class not found in JAR/ZIP; skipping
2016-04-21T15:56:39.554 184668A9 CMOD FNRCE0000D - DEBUG class org.apache.log4j.Logger NOT found by CMCL classloader
2016-04-21T15:56:39.554 184668A9 CMOD FNRCE0000D - DEBUG class org.apache.log4j.Logger found by PARENT classloader 0x876555fa
```

Why?

I'm going to use maven to build my artifacts.
In the pom.xml I have:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ecm.filenet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jace</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I assume, as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595648/ibm-filenet-p8-subscription-maven-dependencies),  I have to add to the code module only my event class since other CE dependencies should be in the classpath.

Comment: What makes you think this indicates an error? It's just a debug message.

Comment: Perhaps this page and it's subpages will be usefull for you, it tells how to configure log4j [Log4j config FN 5.2.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/logging_concepts.htm?cp=SSGLW6_5.2.1%2F10-2-1-29)

Comment: I wrote incorrectly, I wanted to say that my subscription does not find the class Logger. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you think, that Log4j not found?

From log:
DEBUG class org.apache.log4j.Logger **found** by PARENT classloader 0x876555fa