# How to deploy a Java Action Handler in IBM Filenet?

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 and WebSphere 8.5.5 are used in my current project. My goal is a creation Java Action Handlers. I have a jar file with needed functionality. I wanna store action handler as a CodeModule object. 
I can create a code module via Administration Console for Content Platform Engine (acce). But how can i deploy the jar into a CodeModule object via acce?

Answer (score 3):

In FileNet there is a Sub-Class of Document called 'Code Module'.

If you have a properly constructed jar, then using ACCE, create an instance of Code Module (as you would any Document instance) and check-in the instance using your jar file as the content.

In order to create a properly constructed jar, you must have a class that implements com.filenet.api.engine.EventActionHandler (found in Jace.jar)

You then can create an Event Action, that points at your jar, and a subscription that points at your Event Action.

I would suggest taking a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544650/how-to-deploy-an-ibm-filenet-p8-subscription/36559632#36559632) for more information on Event Actions.

Please also read up on the IBM FileNet docs, especially [Change Preprocessors](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/changepreprocessor_concepts.htm), [Subscriptions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/subscription_concepts.htm), and the topics under [Action Handlers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/server_concepts.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have read a IBM docs about Evenet Action, Subscriptions, Code Module, etc. And I have properly constructed jar with class that implements com.filenet.api.engine.EventActionHandler. And I understand how it works except one thing: how can I check-in the instance of Code Module using jar file as the content. [Creating a code module](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc048.htm). In my case there is no "With content" check box during creation CodeModule instance

Comment: When you select "Code Module" as your class, you should get a "With Content" check box.  Easiest thing to do is open the "Code Modules" folder, select the Actions drop down.  Select New Document.  Change the Class to "Code Module" and then select "With Content" check box.